# Remote access to Microsoft Dynamics NAV (C/Side) with native non-SQL database

Tags: database, remote-access, navision

I am facing a company that have a fairly recent Microsoft Dynamics NAV (C/Side) setup that comes with a non-SQL storage system called the [native database server](http://dynamicsblog.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/native-vs-sql-the-evolution/). I would need to be remotely connect to this database, and perform what would equate to SQL queries with very modest needs (no join, no complex filtering).

I am rather ignorant of this technology, does someone knows to how make remote queries to this ERP?

Comment: Joannes - Were you able to find out if you had an ODBC driver available in your installation media?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some quick Googling, it appears that there is an ODBC provider for C/SIDE. I have no idea if the version of it that you have has an ODBC driver available - but if it does, then that is how you should do it.

That's how you generally make remote (or even local) DB connections on Windows - the first place to look, if you're not sure, is to find related ODBC software.